# is there a way to disable javascript debugging on a live server

Tags: javascript, debugging

Is there a way to tell debugging tools (firebug and the likes) never to be enabled for your website regardless of user's browser configurations?

Comment: You can show a message in the page saying "Dear user, please don't open Firebug or it's alternatives for this page. I don't want to share my code with you".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no.

client is free to do whatever it sees fit with your javascript.   You may try to obfuscate - but this is not effective against determined developers

Comment: I know some of these tools allow people manipulate your html code; causing unexpected inputs to a server side processing script. I know a good way to handle this is to write good code. Just curious to know if there are other ways to handle this by limiting such maniuplations

Comment: there are none.  just assume that all data coming from client are complete bullshit and be prepared to deal with it.  everything coming from evil internet outside is untrusted

Answer (score 1):

Scripts, HTML, CSS, Images everything is loaded to the **client** before the page opens. So he can do anything he likes with what he has in his system. There is **no way** to disable it.

*Even If there is a possibility of doing such*, he can remove that as well.

#### So, basically its a wasted effort.